# Codeigniter return unsigned zerofill id from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using this method to get the last inserted id:

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

for example the inserted id in the database is 000055, but this function returns me only 55, how can I get the full unsigned zerofill id?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySQL - the `$this->db->insert_id()` method uses [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function - which returns an integer.

So, without changing the [`./system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php#L362) file, I don't think there's a way.

Comment: so if i change it which method i should use to get the unsigned zerofill?

Answer (score 0):

why are your ID's zero filled? This could cause problems if it returns 1's because it will think it is a binary number rather than a zero filled int. There could even be a rare chance to be hex as well. If you just want your ID's zero filled for the application then handle that in a library or helper for when you render it to a view because since PHP is loosely typed it could think you are doing a bit comparison or dealing with hex or binary and not an int.

If you really want to do this you will need to extend CI_DB_mysqli_driver (or whatever db driver you are using) and overwrite insert_id() and make sure it returns a string and then make sure you always treat it as a string. Still, I would strongly advise you from doing logic on zero filled ints.